# 3D object material goes black when morph target influence reaches value 1

Tags: three.js, gltf

I include an Object with morphtargets and a standard material into a three.js scene ; the object is loaded from a GLTF export done from Blender ; the morphTarget influences values are working right as long as the value is lower than 1; when it equals 1 the object goes to black. Going back below 1 and the object comes back.

three.js r 104 - Blender 2.80 with gltf 2 exporter.
I'm looking for help on what can cause this ?

Comment: Can you please share the `glTF` asset in this thread? BTW: Morph target influence values higher than 1 are not valid since 1 represents the maximum/full influence.

Comment: it is here http://lu-e-lou.com/priv/cylinder.zip ; OK for limit of influence to 1. I also observed it occurs only with standardMeshMaterial ; if I change (after loading) the material to a phong or other it does not.

Comment: Can you reproduce this when opening the model in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and adjusting the morph targets? I can't, so I'm wondering if it might be a device-specific problem.

Comment: No, I agree, I can't reproduce in the GLTF-viewer ; So, the gltf model is probably OK but could this be related to three.js importing ? if not, I have to dig into my part of software (what I did of course for a while without success). But is'nt morph target influence be processed by GPU ?

Comment: blender gltf export delivers mutliple meshes for an object even if they are joined in blender (with ctrl J). I want them to be one mesh in three.js ; so I merge all geometries into one and make a new SkinnedMesh with this geometry and the array of materials. Do you see any problem with this ? Thanks for help.

Comment: OK, I found this is where the problem comes from. If a load the original gltf SkinnedMesh everything is OK. Problem comes with my merge geometries. Is there another way to merge meshes ? if not, I have to find a workaround and this question  can be closed. Thanks for having given feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my mistake. I missed the following line in my code after merging all geometries: 
joinedgeometry.**computeMorphNormals** ();
Everything OK now.
In case this can help someone else ...